# Use multi-threaded make by default?

Tags: command-line, compiling, make, multithreading

Is there any way to have `make` use multi-threading (6 threads is ideal on my system) system-wide, instead of by just adding `-j6` to the command line? So, that if I run `make`, it acts the same as if I  was running `make -j6`? I want this functionality because I install a lot of packages from the AUR using `pacaur` (I'm on Arch), so I don't directly run the make command, but I would still like multi-threading to build packages faster.

Comment: I don't use Arch, so I don't know if it overrides settings when it builds the packages, but try setting [`MAKEFLAGS='-j 6'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html#Options_002fRecursion) before calling the install/build and see if's honored?

Comment: see also: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg#MAKEFLAGS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(pacaur uses makepkg, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg )

In `/etc/makepkg.conf` add
`MAKEFLAGS="-j$(expr $(nproc) \+ 1)"`
to run #cores + 1 compiling jobs concurrently.

When using bash you can also add
`export MAKEFLAGS="-j$(expr $(nproc) \+ 1)"`
to your `~/.bashrc` to make this default for all `make` commands, not only those for AUR packages.